# find side of triangle with given a median, a length of side and an angle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

I try to find value of $x$ but I can apply none of the following properties for that.

```
AAS -- Any two angles, and one side (Law of Sines)
SAS -- Side, included Angle, and Side (Law of Cosines)
SSA -- Two sides, and a non-included Angle (Law of Sines)
SSS -- All three sides (Law of Cosines)
```

Because there are a median, a side and an angle.

How can $x$ value be found?

[image]

Comment: Just apply the sine theorem: the angles at $D$ have the same sine, $\sin 30^\circ$ and $\sin 45^\circ$ are well-known and $CD=DB$.

Comment: how they have same sine at $D$, I don't understand @JackD'Aurizio

Comment: $\sin(\pi-\theta)=\sin(\theta)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The left triangle has area $$\frac12 \cdot 8\cdot AD\cdot\sin 30^\circ$$The right one has area $$\frac12\cdot x\cdot AD\cdot\sin 45^\circ$$These two areas are equal, since they have the same base and height.